# Images not shown in meteor mobile app hosted in heroku

Tags: android, meteor, heroku

When moved my app to heroku, the app images are not loaded anymore in the meteor mobile app (using an android device), but they are properly shown using a browser to access the web app (mobile browser or pc).

If the meteor app is deployed locally (via USB with meteor run android-device), the images are shown properly.  Images are also show right in localhost:3000 via browsers.

The images of my app are loaded from the web and not from files via [image], so this is not a path issue.

I have used the  buildpack "meteor-buildpack-horse" to run meteor in heroku.

Any advice what could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  You need to add a line in your **mobile-config.js** file (this should be located in the root of your meteor folder) to allow the app to load resources from other URLs.   This is the line:

```
App.accessRule("*");
```

This allow load resources from any url.  If you want only allow a specific url, change the "*" with the domain to allow, by example "www.facebook.com"